# SegmentControl doesn't move with TableView scroll

Tags: uitableview, ios6, scroll, embed, uisegmentedcontrol

The scene currently in view is "RunTestViewController". As you can see there is a segment control embedded.

Everything runs fine, the segmentcontrol works, however when I scroll the segment control stays put and end up on top of the cells.

**Is there a way embed the segment controller into the tableview so it moves with the table?**

[image: table view]
Thanks,

**EDIT:

------------------**

I have added this code in the viewDidLoad section:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init ];
    [headerView addSubview:resultsSegment];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

This allows the segmentcontrol to move when the table view scrolls, which is great, however the segment control is now unclickable, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to embed a view or control into a tableview so that it scrolls with the tableview? You should put the view or control into the tableview header.

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,200)];
UISegmentedControl *segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
[headerView addSubview:segmentControl];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Comment: yes, I want to embed a control into the table view so it scrolls too. I will give what you say a go and get back to you

Comment: I have updated my opening post with details, thanks for your help

Comment: If my answer helped, would you please mark it with the answer checkmark? I'm spending a lot of time trying to answer questions to improve my reputation. Of course, I'm glad help more if you need.

Comment: BTW, I answered your other open question with regards to the control being clickable.